ValueError: Unable to synchronously create dataset (name already exists) when saving model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2]),return_sequences=True,name='L1'),name='BL1'))
                             
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True,name='L2'),name='BL2'))
model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(24, activation='relu', return_sequences=False,name='L3'),name='BL3'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten(name='f1'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu',name='L4'))#, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu',name='L5'))#, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu',name='L6'))#, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(trainY.shape[1],name='output'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',metrics=['mse'])

this is my model I am training it and after that i want to save it buy when i am using
model.save("model.h5")


i am getting error as
`File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\h5py\_hl\dataset.py:163, in make_new_dset(parent, shape, dtype, data, name, chunks, compression, shuffle, fletcher32, maxshape, compression_opts, fillvalue, scaleoffset, track_times, external, track_order, dcpl, dapl, efile_prefix, virtual_prefix, allow_unknown_filter, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0)
    160 else:
    161     sid = h5s.create_simple(shape, maxshape)
--> 163 dset_id = h5d.create(parent.id, name, tid, sid, dcpl=dcpl, dapl=dapl)
    165 if (data is not None) and (not isinstance(data, Empty)):
...
File h5py\\_objects.pyx:55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

File h5py\\h5d.pyx:137, in h5py.h5d.create()

ValueError: Unable to synchronously create dataset (name already exists)`

I tried naming each layer from some stack overflow solution but is didn't work
